# matplotlib example code throws TclError

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, matplotlib

Whenever I try to plot anything with matplotlib (f.e. [this example code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/random_data.html)) I get the same error:

```
     jfm@ubuntu$  python test_for_matplotlib.py 
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_for_matplotlib.py", line 5, in <module>
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1046, in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 423, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 79, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 87, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "S_base3"
```

I tried to fix this for several hours now but I don't find any solution on the interwebs :(

I refreshed python and matplotlib:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

but the errormessage stays the same :/

My setup: I run the pythoncode on a 64bit-Ububtu 14.04 VM with Python 2.7.

Comment: Can you please copy the code that you use here? Also, do you use `thinter` or only `matplotlib`?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: `matplotlib` has a Tkinter backend.

Comment: The code is the one I linked: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/random_data.html. No other code or anything is in the .py file I try to run. So I don't use thinter explicitly.

Other libaries (like numpy) work like a charm.

Comment: Can you post the _full_ traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting up a new VM. I guess the old set up was beyond repair.

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: Yeah well. I just set up a new virtual machine and deleted the old one. That was the most time efficient way I saw.

Comment: Ok. I compiled a fresh copy of python3 in opt directory (ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You should choose another backend in your matplotlibrc file (under your home or in /etc/matplotlibrc).
Replace:

```
backend=TkInter
```

With:

```
backend=Qt4Agg
```

Or another backend: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Use `locate matplotlibrc` if you cannot locate your rc file.